# Prove: $G \cong M \times N$ and $G$ is finite $\Rightarrow order(N)$ is not divisible by 5

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

I have the following questions about things I have to prove for my math study:

Let $G$ be a group with the property that $(gh)^5 = g^5h^5$ for all $g, h \in G$.
Let $M = $ {$g \in G | g^5 = e$} and $N = $ {$g^5 | g\in G$}

Given that $f: M \hookrightarrow G \twoheadrightarrow G/N$ is an isomorphism,

Prove:
a) $G \cong M \times N$
b) $G$ is finite $\Rightarrow order(N)$ is not divisible by 5

I already proved that $M$ and $N$ are normal subgroups of $G$, and by the first isomorphism theorem that $G/M \cong N$. I also proved that $M \cap N =$ {$e$} (with $e$ of course the identity element) and $mn = nm$ for all $m \in M, n \in N$

Could you explain me how to solve a) and b)?

thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you prove $\;N\;$ is a subgroup *at all* ?

Comment: @Timbuc That follows from $(gh)^5=g^5h^5$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks, I oversaw that completely.

Comment: For a), it's easy to show that $\phi:M\times N\to MN$ s.t. $\phi(m,n)=mn$ is an isomorphism, since $MN$ is a subgroup of $G$ because $mn=nm$ $\forall m\in M$ and $\forall n\in N$. Since $|MN|=\frac{|M||N|}{|M\cap N|}=|M||N|=|M||G|/|M|=|G|$, $MN=G$. Thus, $G\simeq M\times N$.

Comment: @Aran Komatsuzaki Thank you very much. That's very logic if you see it that way. And how about b)?

Comment: The map $\theta(n)=n^5$ is obviously an automorphism of $N$. What does happen if $5 \mid |N|$? :)

Comment: All elements of $G$ of order $5$ are in $M$. How about Cauchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

b) The map $\theta(n)=n^5$ is an automorphism of n. If would $5 \mid |N|$ then there would exist an element of $N$ that its order is 5, so $\theta$ wouldn't be a monomorphism. This contradiction shows that 5 must not divide the order of $N$.

Comment: I don't see the contradiction. Why would $\theta$ not be a monomorphism if there is an element in $N$ with order 5?

Comment: Because the kernel of $\theta$ contains all elements of order 5. And the kernel of a monomorphism must contain only the e.

Comment: Of course! thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.